# Nonassociativity in Cayley-Algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, non-associative-algebras

Let $(E,s)$ be a Cayley algebra over a unital commutative ring $A$ with unit element $e$ and $s$ an antiautomorphism (i.e. $s(uv) = s(v)s(u)$, $u,v \in E$) of $E$ such that $u + s(u) \in Ae$ and $N(u) := us(u) \in Ae$ for $u \in E$, see f.i. Bourbaki (1989), Algebra I, III.2.4. Is it always true that $(uv)(s(v)s(u)) = u(vs(v))s(u), u,v \in E$ or equivalently, that always $N(uv)=N(u)N(v)$. (Of course this holds if $E$ is associative.)

Comment: Meanwhile I found simple counterexamples. Let  $E$ be the Cayley algebra of sedenions. Then there are zero divisors $u = e_1 + e_{10}$ and $v = e_5+e_{14}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion ) with $uv = 0$, hence $N(uv) = 0$ but $N(u) = N(v) = 2$.